# How do I use php to find an average of two specific keys within an array without averaging the entire array

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to php, sql, etc. and am trying to create a simple member system to intake scores and average specific pairs, but I am not getting the correct result.

Controller:

```
        <?php 
    $records = array();
    $avg = array();
    if($results = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM table")) {
        if($results->num_rows) {
            while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
                $records[] = $row; //Appending value to array
                $avg[] = $row;

            }
            $avg['charAvgScore'] = ($avg['charPreviousScore'] + $avg['charCurrentScore']/2);
            $results->free();
    }
    }

?>
```

print_r($avg) results

```
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [memberID] => 5
            [charName] => Someguy
            [charClass] => Cabalist
            [charLevel] => 53
            [charPreviousScore] => 4
            [charCurrentScore] => 4
            [charAvgScore] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [memberID] => 6
            [charName] => Otherguy
            [charClass] => Abolisher
            [charLevel] => 53
            [charPreviousScore] => 8
            [charCurrentScore] => 8
            [charAvgScore] => 0
        )

    [charAvgScore] => 0
)
```

charPreviousScore is returning an "Undefined Index" and the value of $avg is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve that on your SQL Query with:

```
<?php 
    $records = array();
    $avg = array();
    if($results = $conn->query("SELECT *, ((charPreviousScore + charCurrentScore) / 2) AS charAvgScore FROM table")) {
        if($results->num_rows) {
            while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
                $records[] = $row; //Appending value to array
            }
            $results->free();
        }
    }

?>
```

The result should be:

```
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [memberID] => 5
            [charName] => Someguy
            [charClass] => Cabalist
            [charLevel] => 53
            [charPreviousScore] => 4
            [charCurrentScore] => 4
            [charAvgScore] => 4
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [memberID] => 6
            [charName] => Otherguy
            [charClass] => Abolisher
            [charLevel] => 53
            [charPreviousScore] => 8
            [charCurrentScore] => 8
            [charAvgScore] => 8
        )
)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I hoped for, and one of the first things I tried, but I could not understand how to make it work. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you should be doing the calculation inside your results loop.

```
int i = 0;
while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
   $records[] = $row;
   $avg[] = $row;
   $avg[i]['charAvgScore'] = ($row['charPreviousScore'] + $row['charCurrentScore']/2)
   i++;
}
```